# Grails\Hibernate: To cache or not to cache?

Tags: hibernate, grails, ehcache

What is the best caching policy in Hibernate\Grails. Cache all entities and queries or not and how to find best solution ?

Here my **hibernate** config.

```
hibernate {
  cache.use_second_level_cache = true
  cache.use_query_cache = true
  cache.provider_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider'
  connection.useUnicode = true
  connection.characterEncoding = 'UTF-8'
  connection.provider_class = 'org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider'
  dialect = 'org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect'
  order_updates = true
  c3p0.min_size = 5
  c3p0.max_size = 20
  c3p0.max_statements = 20 * 10
  c3p0.idle_test_period = 15 * 60
}
```

**Ehcache** config

```
<defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="100"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
/>

<cache
            name="org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"
            maxElementsInMemory="50"
            eternal="false"
            timeToLiveSeconds="120"
            overflowToDisk="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best caching policy is: no caching. Seriously, caching (and any optimization) should be done only to solve an existing problem. If you don't have performance problems, don't use caching. If you do have performance problems, then apply this simple 5-step procedure for solving performance problems:

1. Measure.
2. Measure.
3. Optimize (add caching, for example)
4. Measure.
5. Measure.

Note that if you don't understand how the caching works in Hibernate, you can end up having poor performance, instead of improving it. Also, even if you understand how caching works in Hibernate, there may be other effects influencing the performance, causing a database roundtrip to be faster than looking up the cache. That's why you should measure before and after doing "improvements".

Comment: The best caching policy is: no caching!?? Where you high when you wrote this?

Comment: Did you read what I've wrote? If your first instinct when facing a slowness is to cache things, then it's wrong. If are sure that caching is gonna help, and you've measured it, then caching is an alternative. Without knowing how it works, when it works and why it works, it's better to not cache at all.

Comment: I read what you wrote and I agree with the 5 step procedure. I do not agree with the aggressive approach toward caching in general and how you start your argument. There is a lot of dynamic activities and thousands of users hitting databases or other services in large websites. To say best caching is non caching is absurd! ...unless you are speaking of my grandma's blog

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the tone, but I'd keep it. The reason is that most of the applications don't reach even hundreds of concurrent requests, and performance problems that can be solved by caching are not generic solutions and involve a lot of knowledge of inner workings of the application itself. That's why "no caching" is always the best generic approach, except when you can prove otherwise.